# How to send a ZPL string to print on a Zebra printer

Tags: printing, fedex, ups, zpl-ii

I am using the FedEx Rest API to create shipments and I have no trouble printing PNGs. However, I also need to have an option for printing on Zebra thermal printers, which is where ZPL format comes in. I need to print over USB and I am using VB.NET.

I've tried to use GrapeCity's ActiveReports library but I can't seem to find an option for just sending a string/raw data.  I've also tried this [RawPrinterHelper](https://github.com/germanger/zpl-printer/blob/master/ZPLPrinterSolution/ZPLPrinterProject/RawPrinterHelper.cs#L112).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a printer called "TLP2844" attached to my local computer which connects to my TLP2844 via USB.

This is the batch file that I use to print to that printer

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
 IF EXIST "%%a" (COPY /b "%%~a" \\%computername%\TLP2844
 ) ELSE (
  IF EXIST "%%a.txt" (
   COPY /b "%%~a.txt" \\%computername%\TLP2844
  ) else (
   ECHO Neither "%%a" nor "%%a.txt" appears to EXIST
  )
 )
)
```

If this file (I call it `2844.bat`) is placed in any directory on the `PATH` then

```
2844 filename "filename" filename...
```

will print on the 2844. Quotes are only required if the filename contains separators like spaces.

Replace `%computername%` with `servername` if required.

Essentially, all you need is a proper text editor (I use `EDITPLUS` but there are many others) to create simple text files containing the ZPL code.

Don't use a word-processor or `notepad` as these have a habit of "helpfully" reformatting the file as though it was a document.